# C++ How to determine if element is present in a dynamic allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, element

Let's say I have a dynamic allocated array with the capacity of 50.

```
int *myArray = new int[50];
```

I need to write a calAverage function to calculate the average value of elements inside of that array.

Not all index have been assigned a value. myArray may have 0,10, or 50 value assigned.I don't know how many or where the value is being assigned.

So here's my calAverage function:

```
int calAverage()
{int sum = 0;
 int avg = 0;
 for (int i=0;i<50;i++)
 {
  if (element i is present) {sum+=myArray[i];i++}

 }
```

Am I on the right track? and please help me finish the calAverage function.

I cannot use vector or map since this is a assignment, and it's not allowed.
The hint that I received was to create a parallel array and compare the two to check if an element is assigned. IDK the logic of how that can help.

Comment: Do you have a reason not to use `std::vector`?

Comment: There is no way to test elements for being assigned.

Comment: You'll need to specify what it means in your program for an element to be unassigned, and how to detect it - such things are not specified in any way in C++.    Consider using a standard container, rather than using `new`.    For example, a `std::map<int, int>` to represent pairs of index and value will only contain pairs that have been placed in it, unlike an array or vector where all indices are valid in a range.

Comment: You shouldn't really need a `map` for a simple average. Just create a `vector` and just push the values into that. Getting average is trivial from that then.

Comment: I cannot use vector or map since this is a assignment, and it's not allowed. The hint that I received was to create a parallel array and compare the two to check if an element is assigned. IDK how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments and answer by Lightness have written, you cannot really check if an element has been assigned a value. However, you did say you could use a parallel array to help you. What if you used an int instead? When you add values to the array, increment a counter that you pass along with the array. That counter will then hold the 'length' of used portion of the array. May not be ideal but it would work. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

double calAverage(int*, int);

int main()
{
    int *myArray = new int[50];
    int myArrLength = 0;
    double avg;


    // add values to array
    for (int i = 0, add = 5; add > i; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = i;
        myArrLength++;
    }

    avg = calAverage(myArray, myArrLength);

    return 0;
}

double calAverage(int *arr, int len)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    { 
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    return sum / static_cast<double>(len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Not all index have been assigned a value

It is actually true that some of them, under some conditions, if not initialised or assigned, could have an "unspecified value" (and a program reading said value would have undefined behaviour).

So, we could sort of say that these elements "haven't been assigned a value". But I'm not going to do that, for two reasons:

1. You cannot detect this, and
2. it doesn't mean the elements don't exist.

It's not quite the same sort of "haven't been assigned a value" that you're thinking of. So, I suggest you think of it like this: *all array elements exist, always*. It's up to you to either use some other container where you add elements on-demand, or to pick your own way of specifying whether a value is currently "valid" for your algorithm or not.

If you want a list of *x→y* mappings where *x* isn't contiguous, perhaps you should consider a `std::map` instead (though this does bring with it its own issues, namely that it's likely to be slower). Or you could use some sort of sentinel value like `-1` if these are never going to be considered "real" values.